# Can you add two arrays to a constructor in php?

Tags: php, arrays, constructor

I am still pretty new to php. I want to take in two arrays (as constructors) and divide them by each other. Im not really sure what I need to do to make this happen but basically I am trying to  take 5 years worth of sales and inventory data and store them into their own arrays. Then divide those two arrays to get a new array -- inventory turnover.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
class calClass
{
    private $sales = array();
    private $inventory = array();
    private $inv_turn = array();


    function __construct($sales, $inventory)
    {
        $this->sales = $sales;
        $this->inventory = $inventory;
    }
    function turnover()
    {
       $this->inv_turn = $inv_turn;
        $keys = array_keys($sales);
        foreach($keys as $key)
        {
          $inv_turn[$key] = $this->sales[$key]/$this->inventory[$key];
        };

        print_r(round($this->inv_turn,1));
    }
}
$saleArr = array(30000,250000,175000,155000,250000);
$inventArr = array(8000,4300,5500,4400,9800);
$obj = new calClass ($saleArr,$inventArr);
$result = $obj->turnover();


?>
```

Comment: Can you supply what you'd like your example to output?

Comment: I'd like to see the inventory turnover array rounded to 1 decimal (3.8, 58.1, ..)

Comment: Can't you call your turnover function from your constructor then? It appears you've already written the function. $this->turnover(); You can set your arrays in your constructor, as you are already doing.

Comment: Yeah it doesnt work still, I get a lot of errors. Notice: Undefined variable: inv_turn in /in/hV1PX on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: sales in /in/hV1PX on line 18

Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be an array or collection in /in/hV1PX on line 18

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /in/hV1PX on line 22
0
Notice: Undefined variable: inv_turn in /in/hV1PX on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: sales in /in/hV1PX on line 18

Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be an array or collection in /in/hV1PX on line 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
<?php
class calClass
{
    private $sales = array();
    private $inventory = array();
    private $inv_turn = array();


    function __construct($sales, $inventory)
    {
        $this->sales = $sales;
        $this->inventory = $inventory;
        $this->turnover();
    }
    function turnover()
    {
        $this->inv_turn = array();
        $keys = array_keys($this->sales);
        foreach($keys as $key)
        {
            if (!isset($this->sales[$key]) || !isset($this->inventory[$key])) break;
            $this->inv_turn[$key] = round($this->sales[$key]/$this->inventory[$key],1);
        };

        print_r($this->inv_turn);
    }
}
$saleArr = array(30000,250000,175000,155000,250000);
$inventArr = array(8000,4300,5500,4400,9800);
$obj = new calClass ($saleArr,$inventArr);


?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: sales in /in/pnQ3P on line 18

Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be an array or collection in /in/pnQ3P on line 18

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /in/pnQ3P on line 23
Array
(
)

Comment: Editted to fix that issue

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to zip the arrays together like this:

```
<?php

class calClass {
    private $sales = [];
    private $inventory = [];

    function __construct($sales, $inventory) {
        $this->sales = $sales;
        $this->inventory = $inventory;
    }

    function turnover() {
        return array_map(function($sale, $inventory){
            return $inventory ? round($sale/$inventory, 1) : null;
        }, $this->sales, $this->inventory);
    }
}

$saleArr = [30000, 250000, 175000, 155000, 250000];
$inventArr = [8000, 4300, 5500, 4400, 9800];

$obj = new calClass ($saleArr, $inventArr);

$result = $obj->turnover();

var_dump($result);


/*

OUTPUT:

array(5) {
    [0]=>
  string(3) "3.8"
    [1]=>
  string(4) "58.1"
    [2]=>
  string(4) "31.8"
    [3]=>
  string(4) "35.2"
    [4]=>
  string(4) "25.5"

}*/
```